# Knockout: Alert based on property of list of objects on select option

Tags: javascript, data-binding, knockout.js

I know this is a simple change but I have not been able to achieve it despite researching and trying many things. And I am new to Knockout.
I have this select option of a list of objects `Payors` which has `IsValueChecked` boolean property.

```
<select name="InsuranceId" data-bind="options:Payors , 
                                      optionsValue: 'Id', 
                                      optionsText: 'Text', 
                                      value:InsuranceId"> 
</select>
```

I want to create an alert if `IsValueChecked` is `true`, however the value that I am updating is `InsuranceId`. I am trying to achieve this by subscribing to `InsuranceId`.

```
vm.InsuranceId.subscribe(function (newValue) {
    //doing something here
}
```

How do I write this logic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Payors` has to be an array or observableArray, with the options that you want to choose from.

When you subscribe to InsuranceId you will get the selected Id. Use this to filter through `Payors`.

```
vm.Payors = ko.observableArray([
    {IsValueChecked : false, Id : 1, Text: 'False'},
    {IsValueChecked : true, Id: 2, Text: 'True'}
]);

vm.InsuranceId.subscribe(function (newValue) {
    var boolean = vm.Payors().find(function(payorObject){
         if (newValue === payorObject.Id) {
             return payorObject.IsValueChecked;
         }
    });
    if (boolean) alert ("IsValueChecked is true");
}
```

Comment: Appreciate your answer but I need optionsValue to be Id Guid in this case.
Is there anyway that I can use IsValueChecked without modifying optionsValue?

Comment: Noted. I've updated the answer, without changing the html

Comment: Perfect. 
Besides there is a small change in your answer. Instead of checking directly with `payorObject.Id` , I changed to `payorObject.Id()` to get the value. Same in `payorObject.IsValueChecked()` as well.

Thank you very much.